# Как использовать getQueryExecutionCount()?

Tags: hibernate

Коллеги нужна помощь, как использовать метод getQueryExecutionCount(). Мне нужно получить количество обращений к бд. Нашёл  метод но не знаю как его вызвать и в какой момент вызывать что бы он адекватно считал?

Answer (score 0):

Надо включить сбор статистики для hibernate - свойство `hibernate.generate_statistics`.

Использовать API для сбора статистики

```
 Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
 long queryCount = stats.getQueryExecutionCount();
```

подробнее можно почитать здесь https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-count-executed-queries-session/